# Delphi borderless or flat tEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

How can I get a borderless or flat tEdit? I've tried all combinations with BevelEdges, BevelInner, BevelOuter, BevelKind and nothing worked. Apparently this properties are ignored. When setting BorderStyle, the compiler doesn't accept bsSingle, neither bsNone. I've tried to override the default painting at WMPaint, but I can't reach the edges of the control. Thanks.

Comment: What compiler error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set `BorderStyle` to `bsNone`.

Note that `bsNone` is part of the `TFormBorderStyle` enumerated type which is defined in the `Forms` unit. You likely have either defined a different `bsNone`, or used a unit that does so. Either way that has taken `TFormBorderStyle.bsNone` out of scope.

You can do one of the following to resolve:

- Change the name of the `bsNone` that you defined.
- Change the order of your `uses` clause so that `Forms` appears later than the other unit that defines a clashing `bsNone`.
- Fully resolve the name of `bsNone` as `TFormBorderStyle.bsNone`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that the "bs...' are defined in the Forms unit. I just had to add the Forms unit to the uses clause.